# Create a DSN file for ODBC connection Oracle 11g (WinXP)

Tags: oracle, r, oracle11g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to an Oracle Database in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479795/how-do-i-connect-to-an-oracle-database-in-r)

I want to run the RODBC package in R, but I need to establish a connection between the server and R first.

```
library(RODBC) 
connect <- odbcConnect(dsn = "db", uid = "username", pwd = "pass")
```

How can I set up a "DSN" file w/Oracle 11g on a WindowXP pc? Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: But you asked [about it once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5479795/168747).

Comment: Simple answer is go to MS ODBC Administrator (odbcad32.exe) and add new DSN.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Start menu, click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel (Category View), click Performance and Maintenance, and then click Administrative Tools, or in Control Panel (Classic View), click Administrative Tools.
3. In Administrative Tools, click Data Sources (ODBC).

Info taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188691.aspx