# How to connect to Oracle 11g from R, ODBC doesn't work ...(I have uid, sid, host, pwd)

Tags: oracle, r

I am using the Oracle SQL developer to do some work: extract data to CSV files and then analyze the data in R. I want to automate this, using R to do the querys and the analysis. 
I have used R to connect to other databases: SQL server, MySQL, Postgres, but I am finding a lot of complexities to connect it to Oracle.

So, I want to connect to an Oracle 11g database from R in windows. I tried RODBC, but first I have to setting the ODBC following this instructions:

[How do I connect to an Oracle Database in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479795/how-do-i-connect-to-an-oracle-database-in-r)

The DBA give to me the following: UserId, Password, Host, Port and SID

In the "Oracle ODBC Driver Configuration" window I write the following:

```
Data Source Name: SID
Description: Oracle ODBC
TNS Service Name: host:port/SID
UserID: UserId
```

But I receive this error:

```
    Unable to connect
    SQLState = S1000
    [Oracle]{ODBC][Ora]ORA-12514: TSN:listener does not currently know of service   
    requested in connect descriptor
```

So, my question is: How I can connect to Oracle from R? Is there another way? What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Sounds like an Oracle driver problem, not an R problem. Can you connect via another ODBC client?

Comment: Well, I can't define the ODBC connection for the Oracle DB so, no, I can't connect using another ODBC Client, but I can connect using TOAD and Oracle SQL Developer (without ODBC). But, from the R side, I can connect to other databases as PostgreSQL and SQL Server...

Comment: It might be worth trying the [RODM package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODM/index.html) from Oracle, described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/datawarehouse/saternos-r-161569.html). It also uses RODBC, but presumably with defaults convenient for Oracle databases.

Comment: Hi jthetzel, I followed your recommendation, but the RODM package only receives three parameters: uid, dsn and pwd... anyway, I tried it and didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I connect to Oracle using RODBC quite often at work.  Using Windows, I setup an ODBC connection to the DB prior to connecting from within R.  This allows you to check your connection first.

After you are all set, I then connect with a command like this:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("SAVED_ODBC_NAME_HERE", "USER", "PWD")
```

This creates a channel to the Oracle Database.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Btibert3, but as I said in the question, I can't set the ODBC connection... I think that the problem is that I don't know what to do with the data I have (Sid, etc.) Do you have any suggestion? Any help would be appreciated, Thanks again...

Comment: Given your original question, it sounds like you have enough information to create and save an ODBC/DSN Connection.  In Windows, you can create an ODBC Connection in Control Panel > Administrative Tools.  Select your driver, supply the information you were provided, and test the connection. If all goes well, you can save this ODBC (DSN) and reference it as I highlighted above.  If you can't get passed that step, you may need to reach out again and get help on setting up a connection from your machine before using R.

Comment: Thank you @Btibert3, I think that you are right. I would contact to the DBA and ask him for setting the ODBC connection. Thanks again...